# Django: Is it Possible to create a model like Profile Model, to create an instance at the time of registration automatically

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

I have a custom user model and has created a profile model from it as well. so when user sign up a profile instance is created in the profile model as well. Now I have another similar model which is the address model. I tried configuring it in the same way but the address instance isn't getting created. Is it possible to do that? This is just for an understanding, whether similar model like profile can be created.
this is my model.

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    user                    = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    summary                 = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    birth_date              = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True, auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False)
    country                 = CountryField(blank_label='(select country)')
    profile_pic             = models.ImageField(upload_to='pimage/', default='pimage/default.png')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

class Address(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Address'
```

views

```
@login_required
def address_add(request):
    if request.POST:
        a_form = AddressForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.address)
        if a_form.is_valid():
            a_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Address Saved')
            return redirect('user_address')
    else:
        a_form = AddressForm(instance=request.user.address)

    context = {'a_form':a_form,}

    return render(request, 'áccounts/user_address.html', context)
```

Comment: Did you get any exceptions? why this should be impossible

Comment: Yes. I got a RelatedObjectDoesNotExist when I tried to open the address template. The thing is address instance similar to a profile instance is not getting automatically created when a user signs up.

Comment: I think at first you should be sure that user instance has been created correctly and after that, you should try to create address instance

Comment: I think that is because of user instance, your `Address` model does not have any relation to the `Profile` model so why you are suspicious about this model

Comment: See this line `request.user.address` maybe requested user does not have any address so you try to access it and It raised exception

Comment: I think the problem is in your signup template. Even you can override save() method of your user model to created Address instance whenever you create a user instance. Just consider that the save() method will call on creating and updating an instance

Comment: Oh..okay. That could be the reason. I thought it would be created automatically at the instant when a user signs up similar to how a profile is created without manually doing so.

Comment: I updated my answer So please take a moment and look at it. maybe it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override save() method of `User` model to create an `Address` instance automatically:

```py
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):

    # Your user model fields

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._state.adding:
            # Create your Address instance here
            pass


        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you want to know how you can extend the Django user model here is a [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html) that can help you.

---

Even though you can define some signal to create your Address instance after an User instance has been created.

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Address(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_address(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Address.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_address(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.address.save()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess using signals would do the best!